# Implementing xrange

Tags: python, python-2.x, unit-testing, reinventing-the-wheel, iterator

I wanted to learn about `Iterable` and `Iterators` and hence thought about getting my hands dirty rather than reading theory and forgetting it.

I am curious how I can improve readability and error handling of my code. I also thought to practice and include test cases.

```
class foo_range(object):
    """ Custom range iterator which mimics native xrange. """

    def __init__(self, start, stop, step=1):
        try:
            self.current = int(start)
            self.limit = int(stop)
            self.step = int(step)
        except ValueError:
            raise
        if step == 0:
            raise ValueError("Step can't be 0")

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        if self.step > 0 and self.current >= self.limit:
            raise StopIteration()
        if self.step < 0 and self.current <= self.limit:
            raise StopIteration()
        oldvalue = self.current
        self.current += self.step
        return oldvalue



import unittest

class TestXRange(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_invalid_range(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValueError) as ve:
      foo_range(0, 5, 0)

  def test_valid_range(self):
    expected = [0, 1, 2]
    actual = []
    for _ in foo_range(0, 3):
        actual.append(_)
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    expected = [0, -1, -2, -3]
    actual = []
    for _ in foo_range(0, -4, -1):
        actual.append(_)
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    expected = []
    actual = []
    for _ in foo_range(0, 5, -1):
        actual.append(_)
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)

    expected = []
    actual = []
    for _ in foo_range(0, -5, 1):
        actual.append(_)
    self.assertEqual(actual, expected)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `xrange` is an *iterable*. It is possible to iterate multiple times over a single `xrange` instance. `foo_range`, by contrast, is an *iterator* and as such can only be iterated over once.

```
>>> xr = xrange(5)
>>> list(xr)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(xr)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> fr = foo_range(0,5)
>>> list(fr)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> list(fr)
[]
```

To fix that, `__iter__` should return a new iterator object. A simple way to accomplish that would be to make `__iter__` a generator of the values. Alternatively, rename your class to something like `foo_range_iterator` and add a new `foo_range` class whose `__iter__` returns a new `foo_range_iterator` instance.

Comment: What happens when I do `foo_range(0, 5)` second time?

Comment: @CodeYogi If you do `foo_range(0, 5)` second time you get a new object, and iteration starts from beginning. The difference is when you try to use the same object again, like in the demo I just edited into my answer.

Answer (score 6):

**Question**

I am not sure to understand the point of having this :

```
    except ValueError:
        raise
```

**List comprehension**

You have the following pattern :

```
actual = []
for _ in foo_range(XXX):
    actual.append(_)
```

in a few places.

It can easily be replaced by :

```
actual = [_ for _ in foo_range(XXX)].
```

Also, `_` is usually used as a variable name for throw-away values (values that will not be used). In your case, because you actually use the value, it might be better to name it (`a`, `e`, `val`, `i`, etc).

Also, I think this is equivalent to :

```
actual = list(foo_range(XXX))
```

and I'll let you consider this.

**Unit test organisation**

Your `def test_valid_range(self):` test tests multiple things. It is better to split this into multiple smaller tests. Among other things, it is easier to understand if something goes wrong but it also helps you to think about what you are actually trying to test (iterating forward, iterating backward, etc).

**Suggestion**

It may be interesting to try to implement this using a generator defined with `yield`.

Comment: I wanted to let the reader of my code know that the given code block is prone to error, one way was to use documentation and there define all the constraints of the argument. Anyways suggestions are always welcome.

Comment: "I think this is equivalent to" yep, it is.

Answer (score 1):

**Missing Feature**

One missing feature in all of this is probably the most common usage of [`xrange()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange):

> xrange(*stop*)
>   xrange(*start*, *stop*[, *step*])

You're missing the first case! I can't write something like:

```
for i in foo_range(10):
    # stuff
```

You should add support for that.

**Missing Type Check**

`xrange()` type checks it's input. For instance, if I tried to do `xrange(10.1)`, it throws a `TypeError`. You may or may not want to add this, due to all the issues of floating point comparisons that supporting floating point ranges brings up.

**Testing**

You have tests for values of step that are 0, 1, and -1. You should probably have at least one test for a step value of like 5.

**Stopping Iteration**

This is minor, but you have:

```
if self.step > 0 and self.current >= self.limit:
    raise StopIteration()
if self.step < 0 and self.current <= self.limit:
    raise StopIteration()
```

Those aren't independent checks, which suggests that the second should at least be an `elif`. But since the body is the same, I'd suggest just combining them:

```
if (self.step > 0 and self.current >= self.limit or
    self.step < 0 and self.current <= self.limit):
    raise StopIteration()
```

Comment: Interesting! how do you know that two checks are independent? you apply some technique or its just common sense (which I lack)?

Comment: @CodeYogi `self.step` is either positive or negative - if it's both you've got bigger problems :)